# Fedora Server X Boot Problems

Tags: display, fedora-14

This morning when I tried to boot up Fedora 14 I ran into some problems.

I used it fine last night, and nothing has changed since then.

When I boot up F14, it would go to a black screen and sit there and never booted the GUI.  I tried running startx and it returned a No Monitors Found fatal error.  I've spent a couple hours going through the obvious stuff... but I'm still stuck.

I have:

- Ran X -configure
- Reinstalled the ATI fglrx drivers
- Plugged in a monitor
- Uninstalled the ATI drivers
- Ran aticonfigure --initial
- Rebooted several times

Still nothing.  So, after uninstalling the ATI drivers I'm stuck at the blue Fedora loading screen. It fills up the progress bar/"F" and loads to the blue screen but never lets me login. I also cannot access Ctrl-Alt 1-7.

Any idea what is going on here?  Nothing has changed... it's driving me crazy.